# OSX Mavericks open .jnlp 1.7 U 45

Tags: java, jnlp, osx-mavericks

have someone experience with Java 1.7 update 45 an .jnlp files. I would open an jnlp file, but  nothing work. I get the following Error in Java Konsole. I tried to open with terminal. In terminal I get this message:

```
$ ./javaws ~/Downloads/iLinc-session.jnlp 
 objc[428]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Java console:

```
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Java Web Start 10.45.2.18
JRE-Version verwenden 1.7.0_45-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Benutzer-Home-Verzeichnis = /Users/hello
----------------------------------------------------
c:   Konsolenfenster löschen
f:   Objekte in Finalisierungs-Queue finalisieren
g:   Garbage Collect
h:   Diese Hilfemeldung anzeigen
m:   Speicherauslastung drucken
o:   Logging auslösen
p:   Proxykonfiguration neu laden
q:   Konsole ausblenden
r:   Policy-Konfiguration neu laden
s:   System- und Deployment-Eigenschaften ausgeben
t:   Threadliste ausgeben
v:   Thread-Stack ausgeben
0-5: Trace-Ebene auf <n> setzen
----------------------------------------------------
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://195.37.1.97/osmi/download/session.jar
Could not find client
java.io.IOException
    at Session.extractRsc(Session.java:56)
    at Session.extractApplication(Session.java:94)
    at Session.main(Session.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: It's Java **Console**

Comment: This is currently a bug created by oracle in version 7u40. They are planning to fix it during the 7u60 release. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021205

Answer (score 1):

Until it's fixed, here's a work-around that'll @ least allow you to open the .jnlp file...

Open Downloads in Finder
Select the .jnlp file you want to open
Use menu option Open With...
Open the file w/ Java Web Start