# Get error on OS X Mavericks when launching java web start app using SWT from Terminal app

Tags: java, macos, swt, java-web-start

I created an java app using SWT and launching from Java Web Start (javaws). I am using the latest Apple Mac OSX Mavericks and the latest 1.7.X jre from Sun for Mac. I am getting an error about Invalid Thread access when creating display object but I have it in the static main method which I thought is the main or first thread.
I have the command line option -XstartOnFirstThread in my jnlp but no success in getting the error solved. I read that Oracle may have taken away the option for javaws.

Any ideas what I can do to fix? I spent some long hours last night till early morning looking for something that worked.

Thanks!

Comment: You might like to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643720/osx-mavericks-open-jnlp-1-7-u-45 post

Comment: Thanks. I filed this as a bug with Oracle. I think 1.7.0_45 javaws does not pass on the -XstartOnFirstThread parameter to the jre on startup that is in my jnlp. I will verify that today I hope.

Comment: Working with SWT I think this can have a work around if the display object is created in the EDT and passed back to the main thread (static main) and used for the SWT event processing loop.

Answer (score 0):

Until it's fixed, here's a work-around that'll @ least allow you to open the .jnlp file...

Open Downloads in Finder Select the .jnlp file you want to open Use menu option Open With... Open the file w/ Java Web Start

Comment: Hi Dirk. I uusually open the Terminal program then use javaws with the http link to the jnlp file. Once the program as gone as far as creating the desktop link then I can use that if I need to.